# gradle main task to zipup sub-projects distribution files

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project which at main is using java plugin. At subproj1 - thru subproj4 the build.gradle files are also using application plugin. It works well in sub projects to compile the jars (with a main class) and create a distribution zipfile (using resources and dist files).

Now I want to build a 'main' dist zip file, comprising of the contents of all those subproj contents.  I found I can run installDist to unzip to each of the subprojects build/install/subprojN

Now at a loss howto in the main only, have a task and/or dependency to create a "main" dist zip file containing:  subproj1/** subproj2/** subproj3/** subproj4/**

My thoughts are to do a copy from('.').include('subproj*/build/install/**/**')
then zip that up. but havent figured out howto add the task only at main level, plus have it not complain:  NO SOURCE

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that just uses two sub-projects, and does not show the compilation of the `main` code. That stuff should be easy to add. The key to the solution is the `zip` and `zipfileset` via the AntBuilder.

Consider this in the main `build.gradle`:

```
task uberBuild(dependsOn: ['subProj1:build',
                           'subProj2:build']) {
    doLast {
        ant.mkdir(dir: "${projectDir}/dist")
        def PATH = "build/distributions"

        ant.zip(destfile: "${projectDir}/dist/uber.zip") {
            zipfileset(src: "${projectDir}/subProj1/${PATH}/subProj1.zip") 
            zipfileset(src: "${projectDir}/subProj2/${PATH}/subProj2.zip") 
        }
    }
}
```

This will write `~/dist/uber.zip`, which has the contents:

```
$ jar tf dist/uber.zip 
subProj1/
subProj1/bin/
subProj1/lib/
subProj1/bin/subProj1
subProj1/bin/subProj1.bat
subProj1/lib/subProj1.jar
subProj2/
subProj2/bin/
subProj2/lib/
subProj2/bin/subProj2
subProj2/bin/subProj2.bat
subProj2/lib/subProj2.jar
```

Comment: Bravo. Does exactly what I wanted.  Thought gradle proper could handle it... yet another example of needed ant functionality. oh well.